# avformat.h and avcode.h NOT FOUND

Tags: macos, opencv, compilation, avcodec

I am using MAC OSx and OpenCv 2.4.8. I am trying to compile a program which includes:

avformat.h and avcodec.h

I have looked for those files in my computer and they exist (in OpenCv folder).

When I compile like this:

g++ track.cpp -o track -I /Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/include/opencv -L /Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/include/ffmpeg_/libavcodec /Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/include/ffmpeg_/libavformat  -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_core -lavcodec -lavformat

I get the following error:

fatal error: 'avformat.h' file not found
fatal error: 'avcodec.h' file not found

What's wrong??

THANKS A LOT!!

Comment: Those are headers from libavcodec and libavformat. If the libraries aren't installed, install them, add the proper paths to your compilation command using the `-I` switch and add `-lavcodec -lavformat`

Comment: thanks for your answer, so it would be like this? I have this libraries in two folders: Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/include/ffmpeg_/libavformat and also in: Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/include/opencv/ , so how would the whole command be? g++ track.cpp -i Desktop/opencv-2.4.8/3rdparty/include/ffmpeg_/libavformat -o track `pkg-config --cflags --libs opencv`? THANKS

Comment: I don't have a copy of the OpenCV zip in front of me. Does it generally package libavcodec and libavformat? If so, add `-L library_directory_name_here` with library_directory_name_here being the path to the directory containing libavcodec.dylib and libavformat.dylib. you'll also need `-I header_directory_name_here` with header_directory_name_here being the directory containing avformat.h and avcodec.h,

Comment: If they're in multiple directories add multiple `-L` or `-I` switches.... it would be something like `g++ -o track -I header_directory_name_here -I opencv_header_directory_here -L opencv_library_directory_here -L library_directory_name_here -lopencv_core -lwhatever_other_opencv_libraries -lavcodec -lavformat`

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it by building ffmpeg from source.

```
brew uninstall ffmpeg
brew install ffmpeg --build-from-source
```

Answer (score 0):

These headers are part of ffmpeg package. Get the path to ffmpeg installation by running 'brew info' command.

```
   brew info ffmpeg

ffmpeg: stable 5.0.1 (bottled), HEAD
Play, record, convert, and stream audio and video
https://ffmpeg.org/
/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1_2 (272 files, 48.4MB) *


"/opt/homebrew/Cellar/ffmpeg/5.0.1_2/include" should have the required headers.
```